# How to delete a relation of a object in Parse?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I tried several ways, but none of them worked, with `destroyAll`:

```
var currentCheckin = user.get('currentCheckin');
if(currentCheckin){
  Parse.Object.destroyAll(currentCheckin.relation('events')).
  then(function(){
     console.log('Success');
  });
}
```

With `unset`:

```
currentCheckin.unset('events');
currentCheckin.save(null).then(function(){
  console.log('Success');
});
```

What is the right way to do it? There is no much information about it out there.

Thanks

Comment: try "remove" on the array that holds the objects that comprise the relation.  once you have a ref to an object "currentCheckin" , remove it from the array holding the relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in order to delete an object in parse you have to query it first. Once you find the object you can then delete it like so.

```
var currentUser = Parse.User.current().get("username");
var Follower = Parse.Object.extend("Follow")
var query = new Parse.Query(Follower);
query.equalTo("follower", currentUser);
query.equalTo("following", pic);
query.find({
  success: function(follower) {
   for (var i = 0; i < follower.length; i++) {
   follower[i].destroy({
     success: function(follower){
       console.log("success")
      }
    })
   }
  }
});
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what I did because I wanted the events from the check in object/pointer, so I retrieved the events with: `var eventsQuery = currentCheckin.relation('events').query();` and next `eventsQuery.find().then(function(events){` ant next applying your `destroy` for each event.

Answer (score 0):

To remove an event object from the user object relation (events, in your case) witout deleting the event itself could be done as following

```
var user=Parse.User.current();
var eventRelation = user.relation("events");
var query = eventRelation.query();          

const results = query.find().then(function(results){

    eventRelation.remove(results);
    user.save().then(function(user){
    });   
});
```

A complete working example could be found [here](https://jsbin.com/vaxariv/edit?js,output). Just edit the first two lines to meet your parse server settings.